# C# ComboBox SelectedItem not Updating

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding

My problem is that after I select a item in the ComboBox, the first item or "default" item of the combobox stays empty but if I click the combobox the values beneath show up are selectable etc. but I want the clicked one to show in the "default/first" place.

What I tried so far
XAML:

```
<ComboBox Margin="55,0,0,10" Height="20" Width="145" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems, Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModelRefactored}, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModelRefactored}, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Header">
</ComboBox>
```

Property:

```
public TabItem SelectedItem {
    get {
        return _selectedItem;
    }
    set {
        UpdateTCVCollection(value);
        _selectedItem = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
    }
}
```

If I open up the combobox the selecteditem is highlighted, but I also want it to be shown in the "first place" when the ComboBox is closed.

Comment: You need to set UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged at SelectedItem

Comment: @horotab thanks, tried that didnt work out.

Comment: This should work by default? How does your ComboBox look like? Is TabItem a custom type of yours? What type is TabItems and what does UpdateTCVCollection do? Your issue is not reproducible based on the information you have provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a method when the index has changed, then remove the item that the user selected and add it at the begining.

I've set the value of `Sorted` to `false` because that way the value you selected won't be reorganized in your ComboBox.

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    RadItem selectedItem = ComboBox1.SelectedItem as RadItem;

    if (selectedItem != null) {
        ComboBox1.Items.Remove(selectedItem);
        ComboBox1.Items.Sorted = true;
        ComboBox1.Items.Sorted = false;
        ComboBox1.Items.Insert(0, selectedItem);
        ComboBox1.Text = selectedItem.Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the UpdateSourceTrigger to your Combobox.

```
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged
```

Example:

```
<ComboBox Margin="55,0,0,10" Height="20" Width="145" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems, Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModelRefactored}, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModelRefactored}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Header">
</ComboBox>
```

Have a look to [this MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx)

That should help you with your problem.

Greetings